# Open safari when the user clicks on a push notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I want to open the mobile browser when the user clicks on a remote notification.

1) Is this OK, or can it cause my app to be rejected?

2) If it is allowed, how do I implement this when the app is not open? I am currently using the following code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{    
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"received link here" forKey:@"SNL_APNs_LINK"];

     UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];

    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        //app is running
      //only for testing, will add an alert to inform user when published
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"SNL_APNs_LINK"]]];
    }
    else if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive)
    {
        //app in inactive state
        //how do I redirect the user to browser when the app is not open?
    }

 }
```

Comment: Why don't you try and open the push notification as a modal view controller with fullscreen `UIWebView` inside your own app instead of redirecting to Safari?

Answer (score 0):

It's going to depend what website you launch. If the website is "advertising, promotions, or direct marketing", then your app will probably be rejected. If It's something legitimate then it should be fine.

Worst case scenario, you can just embed a webkit view inside your app (although you still can't present ads in response to a push notification).

Ultimately though, you also need to be aware of this rule:

"This document represents our best efforts to share how we review Apps submitted to the App Store, and we hope it is a helpful guide as you develop and submit your Apps. It is a living document that will evolve as we are presented with new Apps and situations, and we'll update it periodically to reflect these changes."

Your app might be one of those "new Apps and situations".